# Possessive pronoun for royalty/nobility

Tags: possessive-pronouns

How do I substitute possessive pronouns **his/hers/theirs/[name]'s** for a royalty/nobility?

Example sentence:  Is this Queen Anne's phone?  Yes, it is ....

But I don't want to use "Queen Anne's" in the response.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. I assume the answer you **don't** want is "Yes, it is hers." Although that's perfectly correct, it's trivial. Could you [edit] the question to be more specific about the answer you're looking for, please?

Comment: I thought it was clear from the first sentence: "substitute ... his/hers/theirs"

Comment: Royalty are still people, why would you think that normal personal pronouns (with the exception of the 'royal we') don't apply?

Answer (score 1):

You could answer

> Yes, it is ***her Majesty's***.

***[Majesty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Her_Majesty)*** is used for monarchs. The 's genitive of Majesty is commonly met with in expressions such as:

> - [Her Majesty's Theatre](https://lwtheatres.co.uk/theatres/her-majestys/)
> - [At Her Majesty's pleasure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/At_Her_Majesty%27s_pleasure)
> - [Her Majesty's Passport Office (HMPO)](http://Her%20Majesty%27s%20Passport%20Office%20(HMPO))

Like any possessive pronoun, ***her Majesty's*** can be used without the noun that refers to the object possessed.